# Find rows between two timestamps -- timezone conversion problems

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I have a column called `time_utc`. This is of type `timestamp`, but it's important to note that the date is always January 1 2023, but at varying times.

I want to return the rows where `time_utc` is between two values ($1 and $2), but these two times are not UTC. They're in timezone $3.

The query is pretty simple (but there's a problem...)

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE time_utc BETWEEN 
(TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-01 ' || $1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AT TIME ZONE $3) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'                                        
AND
(TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-01 ' || $2, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AT TIME ZONE $3) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Here's the problem. All the dates in `time_utc` are January 1 2023. If the user's timezone converts this to a different date, the query will fail.

I'm willing to restructure my database (this is a new project).

Basically, I just want to find times between $1 and $2, but I keep running into timezone conversion problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the dates in time_utc are January 1 2023. If the user's timezone converts this to a different date, the query will fail.

But the user's time zone only converts the *input* value (as it should). The value in `time_utc` is immutable in this. Seems like you just confused yourself?

The only problem I see is an inefficient query:

For starters, [don't use `BETWEEN` with the type `timestamp`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29). Tends to produce corner case errors. Typically, you want to *include* the lower bound and *exclude* the upper. See:

And since all your [time and date input is in proper ISO 8601 format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT), you can simply cast instead of the expensive and verbose text concatenation:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  time_utc >= (timestamp '2023-01-01' + $1::time) AT TIME ZONE $3 AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
AND    time_utc <  (timestamp '2023-01-01' + $2::time) AT TIME ZONE $3 AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

A plain index on `(time_utc)` makes it fast.

Comment: Aha! This did the trick. My query was taking forever to execute -- I thought it was crashing, but apparently, it was just slow. Thank you!